# Reset Scrollview in UICollectionViewCell after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm creating a photo gallery with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rGJ3.jpg) concept. For listing the images, I've used `UICollectionView`. Each image is stored in full screen size custom cells. Inside the cell, I have `UIScrollView` and inside it I have `UIImageView`. `ScrollView` is used to zoom the image. All working fine but, when I zoom in one image and scroll to another cell without zooming out, I want that previous cell's scrollview to be reset.

Inside custom cell class, I set `ZoomScale` for each cell's scrollview when they are initiated like so:

```
func configureCell(_ photo: String){
    albumPhoto.image = UIImage(named: photo)
    scrollView.setZoomScale(1.0, animated: false)
}
```

I configure each cell in `cellForItemAt` function before returning the cell.

When I zoom in in the first cell, scroll to second and scroll back to the first cell, the image is still zoomed in. But if I scroll to second and third cell and then return to first cell, the image is zoomed out to default.

How can I achieve that even after scrolling immediately back from second cell to first, the scroll view will be set to default zoom scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview
and zoom out the scrollView before displaying the cell. This method will handle your case. Happy coding ;)

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Answer (score 1):

First make your class conforms to

```
class profViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
```

As UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView

Second implement this delegate method

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
  { 

        let cd = areaSettTable.visibleCells as! 

       [profTableViewCell]

       //////

       loop here

  }
```

then loop through this array and call the function that resets the zoom for every cell

note : you should change profTableViewCell name to your cell

Comment: I've thought about it but I'm not sure it is the best way to do it as I have to loop through EVERY cell. I may have plenty of cells and looping through all of them just for one cell doesn't seem the best solution.

Comment: looping will be only for visible cells not all cells of the tableview

Comment: How many cells will be considered as visibleCells, is the cell that went out of screen is also included in this?

Comment: No , it isn't only seen on screen and your cell is full screen so maximum number of visible cells will be 2

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks.